# Securing SQL Server Database

Tags: sql-server, database-security

I have my SQL Server running on a remote server. I want to delegate tasks to my team who would be accessing the server to execute the ASP.NET application and hence the SQL Server Database credentials are stored on the connection string.
But I do not want members of my team to take a backup of the database (or catalogs). How would I group the users keeping my SQL server safe?

Comment: This question is better suited for [Database Administration](http://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Define a role and assign permissions to the role. Then assign the role to the user.

Answer (score 0):

You could make two different users on the DB. One with admin rights for yourself, and another for read-only tasks like the asp.net applications. (Rights that dont allow them to make backups)

Give the second user only the required rights, and put those details in the connectionstring.